# Accessing data stored in the memory on a running Python program

Tags: python, memory

I have a Python program that collects data. I have tested it many times before, but today it decided that it will not save the data. Also, unfortunately, I decided to run my program using pythonw.exe so there is no terminal to see what the errors are.

I can see that it still has the data saved to the memory because it is displayed on a plot and I can still manipulate the data using my program.

I want to know if there is a way to access the data my program collected externally or some way to read it.

I know that it is unlikely I will be able to recover my data, but it is worth a shot.

(Also, I am using Python 2.7 with PyQT4 as a GUI interface.)

Comment: Did all the previous testing use a terminal, or has the program previously run ok in pythonw.exe ?

Comment: Where/how were you storing data before?

Comment: I have run it using pythonw.exe previously without any problems.

I am storing all of the data in numpy arrays. There are 9 numpy arrays each containing about 100,000 data points.

Comment: The program is suppose to save the data to a txt file. I wrote this program a few years ago and it hasn't had any problems, but today it did not work and I am hoping to recover my data. Also I just tested the same program on another computer and it worked fine. It was probably some strange syntax error that resulted in it failing.

Comment: How is that possible? The program was running OK for few years and then a syntax error appeared in it? Did you edit it before the last run?

Comment: No. I haven't changed any of the code, but I am running many threads to collect my data from my instrument. I also run threads to save the data and if there was a problem with the response string from the device it could of failed, but that does not seem to be the case. Like I said, I tested the same script again and it saved correctly, but the current script with my data will not. i.e. I do not know why the script does not work. I just know that I cannot save my data.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach to your running process and examine variables using http://winpdb.org/

Comment: That program looks very useful, but I do not see how I cannot attach to a running program to winpdb without the program being started a special way, which mine clearly isn't.